# How to link Standard Token with crowdsale in Zeppelin Solidity

Tags: token, ethereum, apache-zeppelin, solidity

Hello I am trying to create a crowdsale through [zeppelin solidity](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) but I could not find a way to link standard token with pre-allocated supply with the crowdsale.

In other words, I need to have token balances for specific VIP addresses without the need for them to go through the crowdsale!

Comment: Did you find my answer bellow helpful?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is already implemented inside `MintableToken` that the `Crowdsale` token uses.

All what you need is to call `function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount)` that is inside `MintableToken`. You can call it as much as you need and pass the required values with every call.

Base Crowdsale contract: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol

Base Mintable token: 
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol